Sharing UI logic between fragments and activity
I have tried to make my code more modular and reusable by utilizing fragments in activity. The purpose is to have a static activity with a FragmentContainerView that hosts various fragments. Each fragment has its own ViewModel as the business logic differs between them. Still, some parts of the UI (button) stay the same and serve only one purpose. Users can input text in EditText of a fragment and the button in activity is used to confirm users' input but not to validate it as that depends on the business logic of the fragment. Although I managed to get it working it doesn't seem elegant. I am interested in whether there is any better way to achieve the desired functionality or if that approach is even used.

What I have:
First I tried using SharedViewModel which worked but notifying fragment of button click with LiveData seemed like a workaround. Please let me know if there is any better way to achieve that using SharedViewModel. The second option was using Interfaces. It's partially what I am doing now, but only to notify the activity that the input is valid. Implementing the interface in host activity and using it in fragment is easy but how to do it the other way around? I achieved the second part of the problem - notifying fragment of button click - by calling a public function of a fragment.
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.Input {  
    private Button button;  
    private int i = 0;  
    private Fragment fragment;  // I think it would be better to not have class level variable but to inject it as a parameter to function

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
  
        ActivityMainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        setBinding(binding);  
  
        fragment = setFragment(new Fragment1(this));  
  
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                if (fragment instanceof OnClick) {  
                    ((OnClick) fragment).onClick();  
                }  
            }  
        });  
    }  
  
    private Fragment setFragment(Fragment rpFrag) {  
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();  
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()  
                .setCustomAnimations(  
                        R.anim.slide_in,  
                        R.anim.fade_out,  
                        R.anim.fade_in,  
                        R.anim.slide_out  
                )  
                .replace(R.id.frame, rpFrag, "fragment")  
                .commit();  
  
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();  
  
        Fragment frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment");  
        if (frag instanceof OnClick) {  
            return frag;  
        } else {  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  
  
    private void setBinding(ActivityMainActivityBinding binding) {
        button = binding.button;  
    }  
  
    @Override  
    public void valid() { 
        if (i == 0) {  
            fragment = setFragment(new Fragment2(this));  
        } else if (i == 1) {  
            fragment = setFragment(new Fragment3(this));  
        }
        // ...
        i++;  
    }  
}

I'm also wondering if there is a better way to replace fragments in a given sequence and access its private functions.
The fragments expose a public method that the activity can call when the button in activity is clicked. When the input is validated the activity is notified using a callback.
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClick {  
    private final Input input;  
    private Fragment1ViewModel viewModel;  
  
    public interface Input {  
        void valid();  
    }  
  
    public Fragment1(Input input) {  
        this.input = input;  
    }  
  
    @Override  
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,  
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  
        FragmentFragment1kBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);  
  
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(  
                this,  
                ViewModelProvider.Factory.from(Fragment1ViewModel.initilizer)  
        ).get(Fragment1ViewModel.class);  
        binding.setModel(viewModel);  
  
        viewModel.getUi().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<UiData>() {  
            @Override  
            public void onChanged(UiData uiData) {  
                if (uiData.isValid()) {
                    // UI elements update  
                    input.valid();  
                } else {  
                    // UI elements update  
                }  
            }  
        });  
  
        return binding.getRoot();  
    }  
  
  
    @Override  
    public void onClick() {
        viewModel.onButtonClick();  
    }  
}

Although everything works, the approach to solving the problem is not elegant. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions for improving the code.
